Unitary preservation of non-induced norms.
I failed to find a proof of the following, nor know if it is correct:
Let $U$ be a unitary operator acting on a finite norm space $V$. For $v \in V$, $\left\lVert Uv \right\rVert = \left\lVert v \right\rVert$.
In particular, it is easy to show that norms induced by inner products are preserved by unitary operators, but are non-induced norms preserved?

No, the statement is not correct. Non-induced norms are not preserved. Also, if $U$ is unitary relative to an inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$, then $\|Uv\| = \|v\|$ is only guaranteed to hold when $U$ is unitary if $\|\cdot\|$ is the norm induced by the specific inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$.
As an example, consider
$$
U = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&-1},
$$
which is unitary relative to the standard inner product over $\Bbb C^2$. Consider the inner product $(\cdot, \cdot)$ given by
$$
(v, w) = 2v_1 \bar w_1 + v_1 \bar w_2 + v_2 \bar w_1 + v_1\bar w_2.
$$
Let $\|\cdot\|_*$ denote the associated induced norm,
$$
\|v\|_* = \sqrt{2|v_1|^2 + 2\text{Re}[v_1 \bar v_2] + |v_2|^2}.
$$
Now, taking $v = (1,1)$, we see that
\begin{align}
\|v\|_* &= \|(1,\ \ \ 1)\|_* = \sqrt{5}\\
\|Uv\|_* &= \|(1,-1)\|_* = 1
\end{align}
Clearly, $\|Uv\|_* \neq \|v\|_*$, even though $U$ is unitary.
